# How to label the plot, using plot_date and bar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
ax4.plot_date(x=days, y=MACD_14_21,fmt="r-",label='MACD_14_21')
```

I am trying to print label using `label="xxx"`, while plotting the data, but I don't see any label printed.
Do I need to use different syntax?

Answer (score 0):

These labels are for legend only. Add `plt.legend()` to Your code to show it. If You want to add labels on the x-axis You can do it with `plt.xlabel(['label1','label2'])`.

---

Edit:

Unhappily adding labels on plotted lines, is much more complex, and I would recommend You to stick to the legend, because there is no automatic way of doing that. However if You really need to achieve that, it's explained here: [Print string over plotted line (mimic contour plot labels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876882/print-string-over-plotted-line-mimic-contour-plot-labels)

For simple cases You can also use [annotations](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html).

Comment: How can i show label on line . I mean the line I plotted? @Tony Babarino

Comment: Thanks I found same just wanted to confirm :( Thanks